# HAProxy Namebase routing forwarding to same backend

Tags: haproxy

When I'm Hiting **http://drappointment.mytonic.com** it is going to **mytonic_nonssl** backend. But according to the configuration, it should go to **drappointment_nonssl** backend.

Is there any configuration problem???

**HAProxy Version:** 1.5.18

**Configuration:**

```
global
log         127.0.0.1 local2
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
   timeout client 30s
   timeout server 30s
   timeout connect 5s

frontend https
   bind *:443
   mode tcp
   tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
   tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
   acl host_mytonicssl req_ssl_sni -i mytonic.com
   acl host_mytonicssl_www req_ssl_sni -i www.mytonic.com
   acl host_drappointmentssl req_ssl_sni -i drappointment.mytonic.com
   use_backend mytonic_ssl if host_mytonicssl
   use_backend mytonic_ssl if host_mytonicssl_www
   use_backend drappointment_ssl if host_drappointmentssl


backend mytonic_ssl
   mode tcp
   balance roundrobin
   stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
   acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
   acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2
   tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
   tcp-request content accept if clienthello
   tcp-response content accept if serverhello
   stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello
   stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello
   option ssl-hello-chk
   server server1 10.10.17.222:8443 check

 backend drappointment_ssl
   mode tcp
   balance roundrobin
   stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
   acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
   acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2
   tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
   tcp-request content accept if clienthello
   tcp-response content accept if serverhello
   stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello
   stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello
   option ssl-hello-chk
   server server1 10.10.17.222:5001 check

frontend http
   bind *:80
   mode http
   acl host_mytonic_http hdr_dom(host) -i mytonic.com
   acl host_mytonic_http_www hdr_dom(host) -i www.mytonic.com
   acl host_drappointment_http hdr_dom(host) -i drappointment.mytonic.com
   use_backend mytonic_nonssl if host_mytonic_http
   use_backend mytonic_nonssl if host_mytonic_http_www
   use_backend drappointment_nonssl if host_drappointment_http

backend mytonic_nonssl
   mode http
   balance roundrobin
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor
   server server1 10.10.17.222:8080 check

backend drappointment_nonssl
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  server server1 10.10.17.222:5000 check
```

Answer (score 0):

Misconfigurarion.

`hdr_dom` is a "domain match" -- it matches anything perfectly aligned with any commbination of `.` delimiters and/or either or both ends of the string.  It finds domain names matching *or inside* domain names.

For example, this:

```
hdr_dom(host) -i example.com
```

...matches all of these:

```
example.com
www.example.com
example.com.io
us-west-2.api.example.com
```

Your ACL:

```
acl host_mytonic_http hdr_dom(host) -i mytonic.com
```

...matches `drappointment.mytonic.com` and thus this...

```
use_backend mytonic_nonssl if host_mytonic_http
```

....is the path the request takes, since it's the first rule to evaluate the Host header by reference to the ACL.  The first match is used.

Try `hdr()` instead of `hdr_dom()`:

```
acl host_mytonic_http hdr(host) -i mytonic.com
```